# Informatica is it possible to pass a value dynamically from a informatica mapping to a view in oracle

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to pass a value to procedure or view in Oracle from an informatica mapping dynamically?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can Google **"stored procedure"** transformation for passing values to stored procedure.